# Keyword argument aliases

Tags: julia

What's a good way to allow aliases for keyword arguments. Say I want an interface like this:

```
function f(a, b; k1=1, k2=2)
    println(a, b)
    println(k1, k2)
end

function f(a, b; key1=1, key2=2)
    println(a, b)
    println(key1, key2)
end

function f(a, b; kw1=1, kw2=2)
    println(a, b)
    println(kw1, kw2)
end

function f(a, b; keyword1=1, keyword2=2)
    println(a, b)
    println(keyword1, keyword2)
end
```

so you could call `f(1, 2, kw1=3, kw2=4)` or `f(1, 2, keyword1=3, keyword2=4)` and run the same function.

Comment: IMHO it is probably better to write good doc-string for your function. If you insist then how do you like to process mixed alias types (`f(1,2,kw1=3, keyword2=4)`) or ambiguity (`f(1,2,kw1=3, keyword1=4)`) ?

Comment: One reason is that I'm interested in how to "point" one keyword to another, so that it would be possible to, for example, use a deprecated keyword by calling another method with its replacement. `k1`, `key1`, and `keyword1` would be interchangeable; `k1=1, key1=2` should use the value 2, since keyword args can be duplicated (introduced in v0.6 I think).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would really recommend avoiding this, but you can "cascade" keywords together, from left to right in their definition order:

```
julia> function f(a, b; k1=1, k2=2, key1=k1, key2=k2, keyword1=key1, keyword2=key2)
           println(a, b)
           println(keyword1, keyword2)
       end
f (generic function with 1 method)

julia> f(1,2,k1=3,k2=4)
12
34

julia> f(1,2,key1=3,k2=4)
12
34

julia> f(1,2,key1=3,keyword2=4)
12
34
```

Note that you set the precedence order in the definition:

```
julia> f(1,2,key1=3,k1=4)
12
32
```